# Expanding Algebra set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am doing Discrete maths on self-study basis. I am wondering how this set algebra comes about:

that $(A\cup B)\cap (A^\complement \cup B^\complement) $ expands to

$(A\cup A^\complement)\cup (A\cap B^\complement )\cup (B\cap A^\complement )\cup (B\cap B^\complement)$

and NOT

$(A\cap A^\complement)\cup (A\cap B^\complement )\cup (B\cap A^\complement )\cup (B\cap B^\complement)$

Comment: That last one should be correct.  Do you have a counterexample to suggest otherwise?

Comment: The book I am using by indicates the first as the correct answer. I am quite not getting how union/intersection signs come about.

Comment: your book certainly has a typo for the first one; note that $A \cup A^\complement$ in union with anything gives you everything.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(A\cup B)\cap (A^c \cup B^c) &=& ((A\cup B)\cap A^c)\,\, \cup\,\, ((A\cup B)\cap B^c) \\
&=& (A\cap A^c) \cup (B\cap A^c) \cup (A\cap B^c) \cup (B\cap B^c)
\end{eqnarray*}

Both times using the distributive laws of set algebra. So your second answer is right.